# Counting intersecting chords inside a circle

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the number of intersecting chords in a circle with Python. So far, my code keeps returning 6 for the example I'm working on, but it's supposed to return 1.

Input:
2 parallel lists, the first contains the radian measure of the start or end. The second contains the identifiers of the chords. The identifiers are denoted as `sX` and `eX` where `s` is the starting point of the chord, and `e` is the ending point of the chord. The radian measure are sorted in ascending order.

I'm trying to use the line sweep algorithm to solve this. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

[image: cirlce_intersections]

My code:

```py
def count_intersections(radians, identifiers):
    events = []
    for i in range(len(radians)):
        events.append((radians[i], 'start', identifiers[0][i]))
        events.append((radians[i], 'end', identifiers[0][i]))

    events.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))

    active_chords = []
    intersections = 0

    for event in events:
        _, event_type, identifier = event

        if event_type == 'start':
            intersections += len(active_chords)
            active_chords.append(identifier)
        else:
            # Check if identifier is in the list before removing
            if identifier in active_chords:
                active_chords.remove(identifier)

    return intersections

# Example usage:
radians = [0.78, 1.47, 1.77, 3.92]
identifiers = [["s1", "s2", "e1", "e2"]]  # Note the double brackets

result = count_intersections(radians, identifiers)
print(result)
```

Comment: so what does the list of ```events``` look like before you enter the ```for``` loop?

Comment: Why is `identifiers` a nested list, and what do the identifiers even mean? I would expect an input like `[[s1, e1], [s2, e2], ...]` containing the points on each line that define a chord. (And if you really only ever pass two chords, you are only counting in a trivial sense: the chords either intersect at a single point or they don't intersect at all (or they are the same chord and "intersect" at an infinite number points, but chords are uniquely identified by their intersection with the circle, so that's a trivial case to check).

Answer (score 0):

Two chords will intersect if either the start angle or end angle (but not both) of one of the chords is in between the start and end angles of the other.

The first order of business is to parse the input into individual chords. Let's say our chord is represented by a two-element list where the first element is the start angle and the second element is the end angle. Actually in this case it doesn't matter if the start or end point is first since a chord starting at `s` and ending at `e` is identical to one starting at `e` and ending at `s`. To make the calculation easier, let's sort the points so that the smaller angle, regardless of whether it's the start or end point, comes first.

To group the start and end angles for a single chord, let's use a dict where the key is the "identifier" for the chord (i.e. `"1"` for a chord starting at `"s1"`.) We can simultaneously normalize the angle to be between `0` and `2pi`.

```
from math import pi
chords = {}
for angle, point_id in zip(radians, identifiers[0]):
    chord_id = point_id[1:]
    if chord_id in chords:
        chords[chord_id].append(angle % (2 * pi))
        chords[chord_id].sort()
    else:
        chords[chord_id] = [angle % (2 * pi)]
```

Now, `chords` should look like:

```
{
  '1': [0.78, 1.77],
  '2': [1.47, 3.92]
}
```

Next, we want to loop over every pair of chords in `chords` and check our intersection condition:

```
num_intersections = 0
chords_list = list(chords.values())
for i, (c1_start, c1_end) in enumerate(chords_list):
    for c2_start, c2_end in chords_list[i+1:]: # slice list [i+1:] to avoid checking with previously checked chords
        if (c1_start < c2_start < c1_end) ^ (c1_start < c2_end < c1_end): # ^ is the xor operation
            num_intersections += 1
```

---

We can test this by writing some code to generate random pairs of radian values for the angles, and drawing these chords on a circle:

```
import itertools
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def draw_circle_chords(chords):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    
    # Make and plot circle
    circle_t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    circle_x = np.cos(circle_t)
    circle_y = np.sin(circle_t)
    ax.plot(circle_x, circle_y, '-k')
    
    # Plot chords
    for i, c_angles in enumerate(chords):
        c_x = np.cos(c_angles)
        c_y = np.sin(c_angles)
        ax.plot(c_x, c_y, '-b')
        ax.text(c_x[0]*1.05, c_y[0]*1.05, f"s{i}")
        ax.text(c_x[1]*1.05, c_y[1]*1.05, f"e{i}")
    
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    return fig, ax


def count_intersections(radians, identifiers):
    chords = {}
    for angle, point_id in zip(radians, identifiers[0]):
        chord_id = point_id[1:]
        if chord_id in chords:
            chords[chord_id].append(angle % (2 * np.pi)) # I changed this to `np.pi` because I imported numpy anyway to help calculate the coordinates for plotting
            chords[chord_id].sort()
        else:
            chords[chord_id] = [angle % (2 * np.pi)]
            
    num_intersections = 0
    chords_list = list(chords.values())
    for i, (c1_start, c1_end) in enumerate(chords_list):
        for c2_start, c2_end in chords_list[i+1:]: # slice list [i+1:] to avoid checking with previously checked chords
            if (c1_start < c2_start < c1_end) ^ (c1_start < c2_end < c1_end):
                num_intersections += 1
                
    return num_intersections

np.random.seed(100)

N = 5
chords = np.random.random((N, 2)) * 2 * np.pi

radians = chords.flatten().tolist()

s_identifiers = [f"s{i}" for i in range(N)]
e_identifiers = [f"e{i}" for i in range(N)]
identifiers = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(s_identifiers, e_identifiers)))]

draw_circle_chords(chords)
print(count_intersections(radians, identifiers))
```

[image]

For this random selection of chords, the code gives the expected output of `2`.

```
radians = [3.4143139461097722,
 1.7490464303899562,
 2.6673226888342296,
 5.3078849824484164,
 0.029649447885812245,
 0.7638413135112037,
 4.214440793959451,
 5.188985896769816,
 0.8589528357031249,
 3.6134179577142866]

identifiers = [['s0', 'e0', 's1', 'e1', 's2', 'e2', 's3', 'e3', 's4', 'e4']]
```

---

You can speed up this calculation by using [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html) and [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) instead of nested loops in the code that checks the start and end angles. In this case, it helps to have `chords` as a numpy array instead of a list:

```
def count_intersections_numpy(radians, identifiers):
    chords = {}
    for angle, point_id in zip(radians, identifiers[0]):
        chord_id = point_id[1:]
        if chord_id in chords:
            chords[chord_id].append(angle % (2 * np.pi)) # I changed this to `np.pi` because I imported numpy anyway to help calculate the coordinates for plotting
            chords[chord_id].sort()
        else:
            chords[chord_id] = [angle % (2 * np.pi)]

    num_intersections = 0
    chords_list = np.array(list(chords.values()))
    
    # Creates a 2d array where arr[i, j] is the condition chord[j].start < chord[i].start
    c1_start_lt_c2_start = chords_list[:, 0] < chords_list[:, 0, None]

    # Creates a 2d array where arr[i, j] is the condition chord[i].start < chord[j].end 
    c2_start_lt_c1_end = chords_list[:, 0, None] < chords_list[:, 1]

    # logical-and both above conditions, gives us the first half of the XOR expression in the previous approach
    condition1 = c1_start_lt_c2_start & c2_start_lt_c1_end 

    # Similar approach for the second half of the XOR expression
    c1_start_lt_c2_end = chords_list[:, 0] < chords_list[:, 1, None]
    c2_end_lt_c1_end = chords_list[:, 1, None] < chords_list[:, 1]
    condition2 = c1_start_lt_c2_end & c2_end_lt_c1_end 

    xor_conditions = np.logical_xor(condition1, condition2)

    # Number of intersections is the number of Trues in this array, divided by 2
    # Divided by 2 because both xor_conditions[i, j] and xor_conditions[j, i] are True when chord i intersects chord j
    return xor_conditions.sum() // 2
```

Comparing the runtimes of the loopy and numpy functions shows the numpy approach is an order of magnitude faster than the nested loops for calculations involving more than ~20 chords.

[image]

Comment: Wow, there's a lot to take in here...

Will this also work for an unsorted list of identifiers?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing in it code that depends on the order of the identifiers @kyle